# How to upload over 1000 MB data files into jupyter notebook and still be able to run my notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Question is in the title. Basically, I want to analyze a large data file but I can't do that since I can't even run the python 3 notebook that analyzes that file. If I delete that large data file, I can run that same python 3 notebook looking at a smaller file no problem.

Some more background information on my issue:

My file never actually uploads all the way to 100%

[image: uploading]

I can't even open a new notebook that has nothing to do with that file.

[image: opening an unrelated notebook]

Comment: What **happens** when you run the code? I feel like I've processed several GB in a notebook before. The cell just hangs for a bit

Comment: please share the code that is hanging while analyzing the file.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I can't open any notebooks, never mind the one that analyzes my file. I've updated the question to provide more information.

Comment: Is this all local? Can you share the logs of the Jupyer server when this happens?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I believe this is all local. I dont really know anything about coding, I'm just trying to analyze some data that I collected so forgive me for this question but how can I access the Jupyter server logs? I've tried doing 'sudo journalctl -u jupyterhub' but then I get 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' pointing to journalctl

Comment: I dont really know how you installed jupyter to tell if you should be using journalctl, but by default running `jupyter notebook` command would put logs in the running terminal window. Alternatively, you can use `ipython` and process your file completely in the terminal. Or install VSCode/PyCharm instead, which both support notebooks, but are not a requirement